# Resizable SVG boxes

Tags: javascript, svg, draggable, resizable

I have followed the tutorial and the excellent code here https://github.com/petercollingridge/code-for-blog/blob/master/svg-interaction/draggable/draggable_groups.svg

And have a few nice draggable rects on screen. I want to next create a resize handle in the corner but am not sure how to go about extending this code to include resizing. I don’t want to use any libraries.

https://adamprocter.jsbin.com/tulapaj/edit?html,js,output

Comment: If you don't know how to program something, write all actions in plain English, all you have to do then is replace every text line with the correct (JavaScript) syntax. Your project will probably begin with: ``1. create draggable circles on corners that can be dragged. 2. while dragging update <rect> coordinates`` If you can't translate a line break it up in more detailed lines.

Comment: You link to Peters Repo, his blog is: https://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/svg/interactive/dragging/

Comment: Thanks yes that is what I based it on, not trying to add the resizing corner element. Will do as you say to and start the mental model first.